# Javascript to Json (bulk)

Tags: javascript, json, converters

i am facing the problem of having 60k .js files in differrent sub folders, which need to get converted to json.
File looks like this:

```
    var MF = MF || {};MF.RecordingData = MF.RecordingData || {};MF.RecordingData["session"] = {
  "id": "8db467ca2eca3fd8c29a6cdc8434a936",
  "created": "2017-07-23T13:27:03.9186723+02:00",
  "lastActivity": "2017-07-23T15:25:24.0045584+02:00",
  "pageViews": [
    {
      "id": "07230433d646c15e3bfece7728e0d5091f1f34ae",
      "startTime": "2017-07-23T13:27:03.9186723+02:00",
      "endTime": "2017-07-23T13:27:14.9508182+02:00", .....
```

and i essentially need to remove anything before the {. (This is easy for one file, but a differrent thing for 60k files.

I need the data stored in the files as a json or csv file to analyze them in excel afterwards.

Comment: Do you know about `JSON.stringify`? That would be a main tool for me if I wanted to do this.

Answer (score 0):

If you will read this files like a text, u can use `.indexOf("= {")` to find start of your object and then `.slice(index+2)` to cut object that you need.

In example

```
var x = 'dsadadsdsa{} = {"val":1,"val2":2}';
x = x.slice(x.indexOf("= {")+2);
x = JSON.parse(x)
console.log(x) //{val: 1, val2: 2}
```